# Laravel search with multiple selects

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a few selects.  One with 4 options, and other with 5 options.  Originally I was doing something like this:

```
$('.status').change(function() {
    if($('.status').val() == 'Pending')
        window.location = '/cases';
    else
        window.location = '/cases/' + $('.status').val().toLowerCase();
});
```

And then had a GET route in Laravel for each status.  But then I realized, with 4 status options and 5 other options in other select, there's 20 different possibilities.

Is there a more efficient way to do this than creating 20 routes?  Also this doesn't account for routing in the right order (ex: status/other, or other/status)?

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one route and all your selects in one form which posts to that one route when the form is submitted.

If you want to have it post each time a select is changed, you can use ajax to submit the form each time a select is changed and then you would still just have the one route which is returning the necessary data.

## Example

### Route

```
Route::get('cases', function()
{
    // Return some data based on parameters
    $case = DB::table('cases');

    if(Input::get('some_select')) {
        $case->where('some_select', Input::get('some_select'));
    }

    if(Input::get('some_other')) {
        $case->where('some_other', Input::get('some_other'));
    }

    $data = $case->get();

    return Response::json($data);
});
```

### Javascript

```
$('.status').change(function() {
    var params = {
        'some_select': $('#some_select').val(),
        'some_other': $('#some_other').val()
    }

    $.get('/cases', params, function(data) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with your data here.
        console.log(data);
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for 20 routes, you can accomplish this with one.

```
Route::get('cases/{status}/{anotherVar}', function($status, $anotherVar)
{
    //  Do something with $status
    //  Do something with $anotherVar
});
```

**More on routes and route parameters:**
http://laravel.com/docs/routing